# Patching a module-level method in a general way after import

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, monkeypatching

I'll use the following example to illustrate my needs.

Let's say I have a
module `some_path.module.py` with the following code:

```
def method_i_want_to_patch(*args, **kwargs):
   ...  # some implementation here
```

And in other places in the production code I have:

```
from some_path.module import method_i_want_to_patch
```

Now, in my tests, I would like to patch that method for all unit tests. 
I have a base class for tests which inherits from `unittest.TestCase`. However, due to some cleanups and other stuff needed to be done, the patches are added through a method that is used in the individual test cases themselves, which basically has the `patch("...")` call and calls for `patch.start()`.

The problem is that the method is being imported by other modules, therefore patching it there is "too late". One option I have is to change the `some_path.module.py` to:

```
def method_i_want_to_patch(*args, **kwargs):
   return _method_i_want_to_patch_impl(args, kwargs)

def _method_i_want_to_patch_impl(*args, **kwargs):
   ...  # some implementation here
```

And then patching with `patch("some_path.module. _method_i_want_to_patch_impl", mock)` but it changes production code just to enable testing, which I don't extremely like.
Are there any other clean options which will not modify production code but still keep the way the test infra built?

Comment: Read https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch - you patch things where they're *used*, not where they're *defined*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know, and this is why the solution with the `_impl` methods work. The problem is that the method is being called in numerous modules (>30) and that is why I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

From your description I conclude that your dependencies look something like this:

- Your system under test (SUT), that is, the function you would like to test, imports and uses `method_i_want_to_patch`.
- And, the SUT uses some `other_module`, where from `other_module` also `method_i_want_to_patch` is imported.  This scenario, as you write in your comment, occurs quite often.

In addition to the option you have described (adding an indirection), you could do the following:

Alternative A:

Ensure that every `other_module` uses the `method_i_want_to_patch` in the following way:

```
import module
...
module.method_i_want_to_patch(...)
```

instead of

```
from module import method_i_want_to_patch
...
method_i_want_to_patch(...)
```

If this is done consistently, then patching `module.method_i_want_to_patch` will work.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch.

Alternative B:

In your tests of SUT, not only patch `method_i_want_to_patch`, but also patch what is called from `other_module`.  This way, also the transitive dependency from `other_module` to `method_i_want_to_patch` is eliminated.

Final remarks:

It is well possible, though, that in the end your original idea turns out to be the best: Maybe you can not ensure `method_i_want_to_patch` is used consistently as `module.method_i_want_to_patch`, or, maybe mocking `other_module` would be disadvantageous.

You are not fond of this idea of yours, as you mention: "[...] it changes production code just to enable testing, which I don't extremely like".  You have the impression you are drifting away from your "ideal" design "just" to improve testability.  In my eyes, testability is an important design goal, similar to performance.  Keep in mind how little developers are worried to move away from the ideal design "just" to improve performance.  If we are OK with deliberate design changes for performance, why should we have a headache if we do the same for testability?